# How can I access foreign key methods in a Django model?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a table *Product* which contain only the price of the products and a table *Discount* which contains the percentage of the discount associated to the products.
**I want to access the function `apply_percentage` in the `final_price` method.**

In the real code I have different type of Discount for each product, the situation explained is a generalization to let you understand the problem.

This is my `models.py` file:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    price = models.FloatField("Price")

    def final_price(self):
        **return apply_percentage(self.price)**
        

class Discount(models.Model):
    percentage = models.FloatField("Percentage")
    product  = models.ForeignKey(Product)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.percentage

    def apply_percentage(self, price):
        return (price - (price*self.percentage))
```

I use Django (4, 1, 12, 'final', 0) with Python 3.10.12.
Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely access the price via discount object.
something like this.

```
def final_price(self):
    discount = Discount.objects.get(product=self.product)
    percentage = discount.percentage
    return (self.price - (self.price*percentage))
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! That's what I've done so far, but things get complicated at a larger scale and I was wondering if there was a way to access it in the final_price method

Comment: You can access discount object and calculate final price. check the updated answer